# Regex to find UUIDs and Text

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql

I have a string that looks something like that:

```
"name=Guy&Id=e8679b5a-bf27-46c6-aaf0-ef0eced1945e&Family.Id=e8679b5a-bf27-46c6-aaf0-ef0eced1945e,aaa79b5a-bf27-46c6-aaf0-ef0eced1945e,eee79b5a-bf27-46c6-aaf0-ef0eced1945e&Children.Id=bbb79b5a-bf27-46c6-aaf0-ef0eced1945e,ccc79b5a-bf27-46c6-aaf0-ef0eced1945e,ddd79b5a-bf27-46c6-aaf0-ef0eced1945e&Father.Id=fff79b5a-bf27-46c6-aaf0-ef0eced1945e"
```

I would like to have a regex that will find all the combinations (String.Id and their UUIDs) like:

```
Family | e8679b5a-bf27-46c6-aaf0-ef0eced1945e,aaa79b5a-bf27-46c6-aaf0-ef0eced1945e,vvv79b5a-bf27-46c6-aaf0-ef0eced1945e
Children | bbb79b5a-bf27-46c6-aaf0-ef0eced1945e,ccc79b5a-bf27-46c6-aaf0- ef0eced1945e,ddd79b5a-bf27-46c6-aaf0-ef0eced1945e
Father | fff79b5a-bf27-46c6-aaf0-ef0eced1945e
```

I am trying to parse this in PostgreSQL, currently I can parse some of it, but not all:

```
SELECT
regexp_matches('"name=Guy&Id=e8679b5a-bf27-46c6-aaf0-ef0eced1945e&Family.Id=e8679b5a-bf27-46c6-aaf0-ef0eced1945e,aaa79b5a-bf27-46c6-aaf0-ef0eced1945e,vvv79b5a-bf27-46c6-aaf0-ef0eced1945e&Children.Id=bbb79b5a-bf27-46c6-aaf0-ef0eced1945e,ccc79b5a-bf27-46c6-aaf0-ef0eced1945e,ddd79b5a-bf27-46c6-aaf0-ef0eced1945e&Father.Id=fff79b5a-bf27-46c6-aaf0-ef0eced1945e"' 
,'&(\w*)\.Id=([0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{12})', 'g')::text
```

Thanks

Comment: What language/tool are you using?

Comment: I am trying to do this regex in postgreSQL but any language should be fine :) Even here: https://regex101.com/

Comment: Going from one record to many could be tricky in any flavor of SQL.

Comment: I updated the question with something I already wrote, but I am getting only one UUID and I need the part that also will consider the commas.

Comment: "vvv79b5a"? That's not part of UUID ;)

Comment: Don't make a database do what an app language can do easier and better.

Comment: yes, you are right, sorry. Fixed in the question :)

Comment: @Bohemian, If I only had a way to do it in Java or C# (would still need a proper regex). Unfortunately it is given env :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a [regex like so](https://regex101.com/r/BuQjPy/1):

```
(?:name=[^&]+&Id=[^&]+)?&([a-zA-Z]+).Id=([^&]+)
```

with a replacement of:

```
$1 | $2\n
```

What it does:

First it looks for an optional occurrence of `name=[^&]+&Id=[^&]+`, which is `name=`, followed by at least one non `&` character (`[^&]+`), followed by `&Id=`, followed by at least one non `&` character (`[^&]+`). This is all wrapped in a non capturing group `(?: ... )`, and is followed by an `?` to indicate that the group is optional.

The rest of the regex, looks for an `&`, followed by the first capturing group (`$1`) containing at least one alphabet character (`([a-zA-Z]+)`), followed by `.Id=`, followed by the second capturing group (`$2`) of at least one non `&` character (`([^&]+)`).